# how to do complete multiple replaces throughout table in ms-access

Tags: sql, ms-access

i am a little confused in finding out what would be the best way to replace all occurances of 
1. Blanks
2. -
3. NA 
from all collumns of TableA with question mark ? charachter.

Sample Row in orignal tableA

```
444586  RAUR    <blank> 8   570 NA  -   13  -   SCHS299 MP  339 70  EN  <blank>
```

Same Row in Expected TableA

```
444586  RAUR    ? 8 570 ?   ?   13  ?   SCHS299 MP  339 70  EN  ?
```

please help me out

I cant use the Find Replace Toolbar of access.

Comment: Please give some sample data, and expected data.

Comment: OK, so you want to generically replace accross columns

Comment: "replace all occurances of [some magic values] with [a new magic value]" -- not a nice design.

Comment: @silverkid You seem to be posting more than one very similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1865147/can-i-combine-these-update-queries-into-one-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this for all columns you require

```
UPDATE Table1 SET 
Table1.Col1 = IIf(Trim([COL1]) In ("","-","NA"),"?",[Col1]), 
Table1.Col2 = IIf(Trim([COL2]) In ("","-","NA"),"?",[Col2]), 
Table1.Col3 = IIf(Trim([COL3]) In ("","-","NA"),"?",[Col3]), 
Table1.Col4 = IIf(Trim([COL4]) In ("","-","NA"),"?",[Col4]), 
Table1.Col5 = IIf(Trim([COL5]) In ("","-","NA"),"?",[Col5]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE tableA
SET myColumn = "?"
WHERE TRIM(myColumn) = "" OR TRIM(myColumn) = "-" OR TRIM(myColumn) = "NA"
```

Note: Take the backup of the table, before executing this statement.

Comment: I suspect that that doesn't answer the question specifically: "from all collumns". To do an update on a named column is easy, the logic to identify the column names and create queries based upon that is a bit more interesting.